# Remove labels with pgfplots

Tags: pgfplots

How to remove extreme labels on each axis ?

Why does the shape of the curve is not limited to the upper edge of the grid ?

I find that the curve is not very smooth, especially at the apex of the parabola. I am a user Metapost, and I do not have this trouble if I draw the same curve.

```
   \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article} 
   \usepackage{geometry}
   \geometry{margin=1in} 
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
   \usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.misc}
   \usepackage{pgfplots}
   \pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

   \begin{document}
   \begin{center}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
     restrict x to domain=-3:3, xmax=3, xmin=-3,
     restrict y to domain=-3:5, ymax=5, ymin=-3,
     x=1cm,
     y=1cm,
     axis lines=middle,
     line width = 0.35mm,
     xtick={-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3},
     ytick={-3,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5},
     grid=major,
     >=stealth,
     compat=newest,
     x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.98,0.32)},anchor=south},
     y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,0.98)},rotate=-90,anchor=east},
     xlabel={$x$},
     ylabel={$y$}, 
      ]
     \addplot [red,line width=1,smooth,domain=-3:3] {2*x^2-x-2} ;
     \node[below right] at (1,-1){A}; 
     \node[below left] at (0,0){$0$}; 
     \node[fill=red,circle,scale=0.3] at (1,-1){};
     \end{axis}
     \end{tikzpicture} 
     \end{center}
     \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Which labels are the "extreme" ones? Could you also clarify what you mean by limited to the upper edge of the grid?

Comment: @Christopher Thank you for your reply. Indicating `samples=300`, you solved a problem. In terms of extreme labels, I want to remove -3 and 3 on the x-axis and -3 and 5 and the y-axis.

Comment: Just the labels? If so please see my updated answer. If you want to shrink the graph to not include these areas then you can change the domain.

Comment: I see! I didn't realise you still wanted the ticks just without the labels. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: @Christopher Thank you, sorry for my english still be improved:-)

Comment: I see you are using compat=1.8. If there is no particular reason, consider upgrading to 1.12. 1.8 is kind of getting old.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding additional samples seems to make the curve go all the way to the top of the grid. This is achieved by adding `samples=300,` to your axis.

To remove the labels but not remove the ticks as you requested you can employ the `xticklabels`and `yticklabels` options to specify where to place the labels. The `\empty` bits make the label blank and if you don't include them the labels will shift.

```
  \documentclass[11pt,a4paper]{article} 
   \usepackage{geometry}
   \geometry{margin=1in} 
   \usepackage{tikz}
   \usepackage{tkz-euclide}
   \usetikzlibrary{calc,shapes.misc}
   \usepackage{pgfplots}
   \pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}

   \begin{document}
   \begin{center}
   \begin{tikzpicture}
   \begin{axis}[
     restrict x to domain=-3:3, xmax=3, xmin=-3,
     restrict y to domain=-3:5, ymax=5, ymin=-3,
     x=1cm,
     y=1cm,
     axis lines=middle,
     line width = 0.35mm,
     xtick={-2,-1,0,1,2},
     xticklabels={\empty,-2,-1,0,1,2},
     ytick={-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4},
     yticklabels={\empty,-2,-1,0,1,2,3,4,\empty},
     grid=major,
     samples=300,
     >=stealth,
     compat=newest,
     x label style={at={(axis description cs:0.98,0.32)},anchor=south},
     y label style={at={(axis description cs:0.5,0.98)},rotate=-90,anchor=east},
     xlabel={$x$},
     ylabel={$y$}, 
      ]
     \addplot [red,line width=1,smooth,domain=-3:3] {2*x^2-x-2} ;
     \node[below right] at (1,-1){A}; 
     \node[below left] at (0,0){$0$}; 
     \node[fill=red,circle,scale=0.3] at (1,-1){};
     \end{axis}
     \end{tikzpicture} 
     \end{center}
     \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of increasing the number of samples (which will increase compilation time), you can just use `y domain=-3:5` instead of `restrict y to domain=-3:5`.

Comment: @erik This is true, but the curve is less smooth.

Comment: Of course the curve will be more smooth with more than 10x the default number of samples. I just wanted to point out there is an alternative way to extend the curve.

Comment: @erik Indeed. The number of samples can be tuned of course to reduce compile time I just used it as an example and it's a fortunate double fix of OP's problem.